# Returning blob data from MySQL in PHP and converting to base64_encode to add to an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, base64, blob

I'm attempting to retrieve all the data from a table in MySQL and add it to an array.

[image: Click for Table columns structure]

I want to convert the blob into an encoded string and add it to an array with the other two columns and then return it as a JSON string. See below for my attempted code:

```
<?php 
//Importing Database Script 
require_once('dbConnect.php');

//Creating sql query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM picture";

//getting result 
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

//creating a blank array 
$result = array();

//looping through all the records fetched
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

    //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
    array_push($result,array(
        "pictureID"=>$row['pictureID'],
        "listingID"=>$row['listingID'],
        "listingImage"=>$row [base64_encode('listingImage')]
    ));
}

//Displaying the array in json format 
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

mysqli_close($con);
```

The code is currently returning with a null value for the blob image.

Comment: try `"listingImage"=>base64_encode($row['listingImage'])`

Comment: of course all this mess could have been avoided if you had saved files on the filesystem as they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the line :

```
"listingImage"=>$row [base64_encode('listingImage')]
```

to

```
"listingImage"=> base64_encode($row["listingImage"]);
```